# Shiny project works online, fails to run in R studio

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to run the shiny app locally (https://github.com/holtzy/GenMap-Comparator), but I get this error

```
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Stack trace (innermost first):
49: tag
48: tags$a
47: tag
46: tags$li
45: FUN
44: lapply
43: buildTabset
42: navbarPage
41: shinyUI
1: shiny::runApp
Error : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

When I run it online there is no issue whatsoever.

Comment: Do you have the libraries installed, is your work space clean, and no other libraries loaded when you start the app?

Comment: yes, everything is installed and cleaned to my knowledge.

Comment: if you just type `tag` in your console, does it show sth like `function (`_tag_name`, varArgs)`...